# Calculating probability of game ending after $n$ flips

Tags: probability, markov-chains, fibonacci-numbers

Two players A and B flip a coin sequentially. The game finishes when the sequence TTH is formed and player A wins or the sequence HTT is formed and player B wins. What is the probability that the game will finish at the $n$-th flip?

What I did:

- A wins iff the sequence is $n-1$ T's followed by a single H : $\frac{1}{2^n}$
- B wins iff the sequence ends with HTT and we have no two consecutive T's in the first $n-3$ flips: this happens (I think) with probability $\frac{F_{n-2}}{2^n}$ where $F_{n}$ is the $n$-th Fibonacci number. I proved this by induction.
- Thus, the total probability is $\frac{F_{n-2}+1}{2^n}$

Can someone verify that this is correct and/or share how you would solve this problem?

If the answer is correct, then by summing over all $n$ we can obtain an interesting identity involving the Fibonacci numbers!

Comment: Did you perhaps mean $F_{n-2}$? Otherwise looks good (for $n\ge 3$).

Comment: @zhoraster Thanks. I wasn't sure about this since the document I found this problem in had a different answer; $(\frac{3}{4})^{n-3} \cdot\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: This different answer is incorrect. E.g. for $n=5$ you can calculate the probability by hand, it equals $1/8$.

Comment: Per your interesting identity: it reads, 
$\sum_{n\ge 3}  (F_{n-2}+1) 2^{-n} = 1$, which is equivalent to $\sum_{k\ge 1} F_k 2^{-k} = 3$. However, it is well known that $\sum_{k\ge 1} F_k x^k = \frac{x+x^2}{1-x-x^2}$ (the Fibonacci generating function), hence $\sum_{k\ge 1} F_k 2^{-k} = \frac{3/4}{1-3/4} = 3$. So while the identity is interesting, it is not surprising.

Answer (score -1):

In the first three tosses, one of the players will win is $\frac{2}{8}$ i.e HTT and THH are the winning flips out of $2^3$.  Thus the proability the game will end in 3 tosses is $\frac{1}{4}$.  In an addtional toss, one of the players will win is $\frac{4}{16}$, i.e THTT, HHTT, TTHH, HTHH are the winning flips out of $2^4$. Thus the probability that the game will end in 4 tosses is equal to game not ending in the first three tosses and ends in the fourth toss and thus  equal to $\frac{3}{4}.\frac{4}{16}$ $=(\frac{3}{4})^{4-3}.\frac{1}{4}$  Extending the logic, you will have the probability that the game will end ( in other words one of the players will win) in n flips is $=(\frac{3}{4})^{n-3}.\frac{1}{4}$. The book is correct in its solution.

Comment: for HTTH, the game ends after 3 flips

Comment: You are right.  The solution is for strings HTT and THH and I believe either there is a typo in your book's question or you copied down the problem incorrectly.  Your solution may be right for the two strings HTT and TTH.